# How can I boot directly to Ubuntu after removing Windows from a dual boot?

Tags: boot, grub2

I just removed windows from my laptop completely. I will install it on virtual box.
My question is now, how and from where do I edit the boot options to boot directly in Ubuntu after I open my laptop without passing through the boot options page or if this is not possible, how do I remove the Windows boot line from there?

Comment: Try this: Hit (Alt+Ctrl+T) to open terminal and run this command: `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Uuuups :D indeed. After updated from terminal, windows boot option gone.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit grub to don't wait any second (instead of 10 seconds) and boot the first option in the menu:

1) <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

2) Search for the line "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10" and change it to "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0"

3) Open a terminal and paste: `sudo update-grub`