# Grub starts on bootup on USB Flash Drive

Tags: grub2, usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 to a 64gb USB Flash drive so I have my desktop and apps wherever I go. (3 partitions, swap, boot and home)

I've set up a netbook to boot to USB drive but instead of booting directly to Ubuntu, it starts in GRUB.

How do I get it to boot directly without the pause for me to make a selection in GRUB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can edit grub to don't wait any second (instead of 10 seconds) and boot the first option in the menu:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Search for the line "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10" and change it to
  "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0"
- edit the "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false" to read "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
- Open a terminal and paste: `sudo update-grub`

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/143503/294611)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still keeps stopping there even after making the change you advised

Comment: @BarneyG I have updated my answer please look at it.

Comment: Thanks again but the problem persists. I don't know what it is that I'm doing wrong. I'm booting to a USB Flash drive that I created with Startup Disk Creator, select "Live-install" then I add the second USB Flash drive and go through the steps to partition the drive with swap on dev/sb1, dev/sb2 is set to "/" dev/sb3 is set to /home. Everytime I do this, the UUID for the swap partition on my normal Ubuntu install is changed and the USB drive that I'd like to "work" from on any computer is still having problems in that the grub menu appears. Any thoughts on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: @BarneyG instead of taking soo much trouble you could have set timeout to small value like 3 or 5 sec and let it choose ubuntu automatically

Comment: @BarneyG I am sorry can you please explain me again. I dont understand why you are using two USB. if its a different question from the question above then start a new question so that it will get more attention.

Comment: I'm using a laptop w/o a DVD drive to create a bootable USB drive that I can use on any computer. The only way that I'm aware of on how to do this is to boot to a Live/Live-Install USB drive, choose Live-install and then install not on the laptop's hard drive or the first USB drive (with the install files), but the 2nd USB drive that I want to be able to use on different computers. Ultimately, what I'm looking for is a USB drive that boots directly into Ubuntu with all configurations, apps and files just as I last left them so I can plug in this USB drive, boot and get to work. Hope this helps

Comment: you are using 2 usbs which is not allowing you to install. create a small partition on you laptop then burn ubuntu on it, then boot from it to install ubuntu on USB(only one usb needs to be plugged not more than one). this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077113) may help

Comment: Edward: Thanks for your response. I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible. I do have Ubuntu installed on this laptop but there is no way to install a working copy of Ubuntu via a Ubuntu install. Only to make an additional "Startup Disk." I already have that, and in fact created it onto a USB drive using this install. Your link only referenced some some guy's question on booting to an ISO which is unrelated and not possible

Comment: @BarneyG you can borrow/buy external DVD writer than install on USB